# Deploy ASP.NET Core 5 Web API on IIS

Tags: .net, sql-server, iis

I have implemented an ASP.NET Core 5 Web API project and I published it on IIS. The way I published is that I right-clicked on the solution and clicked published and then I used publish to a folder and after I added the website on the IIS, I gave the folder to that on port 8082.

So now I'm able to use `localhost:8082` to see the swagger of the APIs but:

- I can't see the swagger using my IP address with 8082 port
- When I try to call an API method, I get this error:

  > Login failed for user 'Something\Something-M$'.

which is the user of my windows, but I am giving the connection string to it and the connection string is using SQL connection not using windows login for database connection. Here is my SQL server connection string:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "SqlConnection": "server=. ; database=something; User Id=something; password=something; Integrated Security=true ; Encrypt= false "
},
```

also when I delete `Integrated Security=true` from the connection string and call one of the API methods, I get this error:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.)

Could anyone tell me what is the problem with that? I would be very appreciative if anyone could help.

Comment: Have you checked the (32-bit and 64-bit) Client Protocols configuration in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager yet? Seems like you may have the TCP/IP protocol disabled, or at least a lesser priority than the Shared Memory protocol.

Comment: A beginner can easily miss the key differences, https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 `Integrated Security=true` should never be there (as it allows your logon account to be used), and you should make sure the SQL Server user `something` has been granted necessary permissions to connect/consume the database. "I can't see the swagger using my IP address with 8082 port" is caused by the actual site binding on IIS, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.